# Hard drive split into 2 drives, but one drive not accessible

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a 1000gb hard drive installed on my laptop, which appears to be split into two partitions. Before I factory reset my pc, both drives (C and Data drives) showed in my computer and were equally split with approx 500gb each. Now only C drive shows with 453gb.

Both drives are listed in disk management. C drive is split into 12gb healthy (recovery partition), 102mb system reserved, and 453gb.

The other drive just shows 465gb (recovery partition). it has a blue primary partition bar running all the way along. I only get 'help' when I try and right click on the drive. I can't see any way to format it merge it with the other one.

I just want this drive to show up in my computer so that I can save to it. Can anyone help me out. I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try Free EaseUS® Partition Master 9.1.1 Home Edition or gparted. With gparted you will need to burn it to a disk. That's the best I can offer you.